# Pandas groupby rows into list and sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a multi-index pandas dataframe with the below data:

```
          F     M   
         0  5  10 30
x  y  a1  0  1  0  1
      a2  1  0  0  0
      a3  0  1  0  1
      a4  0  1  0  2
x1 y1 a1  0  1  1  4
      a2  0  1  0  1
      a3  1  1  0  1
      a4  2  1  1  2
x2 y2 a1  0  0  0  0
      a2  0  0  0  0
```

I want to group the data through (A, B) and consolidate column C in a list along with the sum of the rows.

Required output:

```
              sex             F               M
              counts          0  5  10  30    0  5  10  30
     A  B  C
     x  y  [a1,a2,a3, a4]     1  3   3   1    0  3   0   4

     x1 y1 [a1, a2, a3, a4]   3  4   4   0    3  0   1   8

     ......
```

I have tried `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()` but it ignores column C in the output dataframe.

---

**Code To Reproduce**

```
index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['x', 'x1', 'x2'], ['y', 'y1', 'y2'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]])

columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['F', 'M'], [0, 5, 10, 30]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]])

data = np.array([
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 4],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

Comment: Can you print `df.head(10).to_dict()` and paste the output here? It is crucial to reproducing this data.

Comment: Updated the description with the requested output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `sum` for aggregating the numeric data, and `apply(tuple)` for aggregating the index level.

```
g = df.reset_index(level=-1).groupby(level=[0, 1])
res = g.sum().set_index(g.level_2.apply(tuple), append=True)
```

```
print(res)
                          F     M   
                       0  5  10 30
      level_2                     
x  y  (a1, a2, a3, a4)  1  3  0  4
x1 y1 (a1, a2, a3, a4)  3  4  2  8
x2 y2 (a1, a2)          0  0  0  0
```

Note, the index can only contain hashable values, and lists are not hashable, so tuples are the next best thing.

Comment: How do you print the above output. Is it print(df) or print(g) ?

Comment: Thank You @coldspeed !!